# What is this line of Yii code trying to do?

Tags: php, yii

Just a quick question. I see the following code in an extension and I am not sure what it is doing.

```
public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new User('register');  <----(this is the line I am confused about)
    //other stuff...
}
```

What is the "('register')" doing there? Is it an argument going into the 
"User" class? I've looked in the user model, useridentidy, and webuser, and cwebuser classes, but can't find anything. I know that without the proper context, this might be difficult to explain, but in general, what is this extra stuff after the declaration of a new object in Yii? I've been creating objects to use as active records by just typing this:

```
$model = new User;
```

(using the "User" class again just as an example)

I'd appreciate any help to clarify this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [scenario](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios). Models in Yii can have multiple "scenarios" affecting how validation is performed and which attributes can be assigned in bulk. In this case an object of `User` class is instantiated with the `register` scenario, which defines a registration-specific set of validation rules.

Comment: Ah, scenario! So that's what it is. I had forgotten what it was and couldn't for the life of me figure it out. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

```
$model = new User('register');
```

This line is for binding the object i.e **$model in this case** to a scenario which is 'register'.
It is similar to

```
$model=new User;
$model->scenario='register';
```

You can **set the scenario in this way too**. But in order to avoid multiple lines or for the ease of the developers it can be done in this way too :)

Comment: Thanks for the alternative setting of a scenario. Useful

Answer (score 1):

Also you can call different scenario in one model:

In your Model rules function:

```
 public function rules(){
    return array(
        array('username,email', 'required','on'=>'register,update'),
        array('firstname,lastname', 'required','on'=>'other scenario here'),
     );
  }
```

And where you want to call your custom scenario like in Controller action!

```
  $model = new User('update');
```

Or

```
 $model = new User('register');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an argument being passed to the constructor. Look in the User class for a function called `__construct`, it will probably accept an argument, and you can see what it is doing.

This is not unique to Yii, any class can accept arguments in it's constructor.